# Inter-processor communication between AutoSAR and FreeRTOS

Tags: ipc, freertos, autosar

0

I am using NXP 5748G EVB board (Tri-core) in which AutoSAR running on core0 and FreeRTOS on core1. My task is to establish inter-processor communication between two operating systems.

I have gone through Remote processor messaging (RPMsg-Lite) in FreeRTOS. But, I'm not sure if the RpMsg-Lite can be ported to AutoSAR. It would be really helpful for me if someone shares their experience in this topic or suggest some other approaches to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are on the classic platform for now.

Basically you have to implement a [Complex Device Driver](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/20-11/AUTOSAR_EXP_CDDDesignAndIntegrationGuideline.pdf).

The simplest way then is to have sender-receiver or client-server interfaces to your software components.

The other option is that you interface it with the PDU Router and have all the AUTOSAR compliant signal handling, which includes safety and security measures.
This is described in chapter 7.3.5.1 of the above document and chapter 7.7 of the [Specification of the PDU Router](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/20-11/AUTOSAR_SWS_PDURouter.pdf).